# How to downgrade gtk+2.0 package to workaround bug #693758?

Tags: package-management, 11.04, gtk, downgrade

As it seems that I've been hit by [the bug #693758](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/693758) I am willing to downgrade [gtk+.2.0](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0) from 2.23.3 to 2.23.2. But it seems that I have no package with such a name in my system :-( how do I downgrade it then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case for 32-bit:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/60749847/libgtk2.0-0_2.23.2-0ubuntu4_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all libgtk2.0-0_2.23.2-0ubuntu4_i386.deb
```

or for 64-bit

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/60749886/libgtk2.0-0_2.23.2-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all libgtk2.0-0_2.23.2-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

If the previous version is still available from the repositories you should be able to list it with:

```
apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-0
```

To install a specific version of a package use (on this example the version is 2.22.0-0ubuntu1):

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0=2.22.0-0ubuntu1
```

Please note that downgrading packages is not supported, but likely to work without problems in most cases.

Comment: The version is not found. What to do then? The bug is very annoying (can't switch language, can't use clipboard, can't use Flash, etc...)

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you running ?